# Error while declaring array >> int arr[]; in C++ (valid in Java though)?

Tags: java, c++, arrays

Why can we not declare arrays with an unspecified size `int arr[];` in C++ like Java? When I tried it gives an error.

Is it possible without using `std::vector`?

PS. update 3 aug 11.24 pm IST
apologies to all i was confused regarding this

> > int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};

as far as i could understand Does it mean that we cannot declare a array in C++ without initialising it like above ?
, please do correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: You might as well ask why you can't feed Perl to a Python interpreter, or why you can't run Julia code in bash, or...

Comment: Because C++ is not Java

Comment: @CharlesDuffy could you please tell why , sorry i am a beginner if the question is too simple

Comment: Why C++ -- a language which was written long *before* Java -- doesn't support Java syntax? Why would you ever expect that it *would*?

Comment: because this ain't Java :(

Comment: Because C++ is user friendly but it is picky with friends

Comment: @Oblivion could you please elaborate?

Comment: @cybrpnkkrtos C++ offers freedom and flexibility  but that comes at the price of complexity

Comment: Note: In Java the standard form is `int[] arr;` rather than `int arr[];` (although they do the same thing).

Comment: Because in Java it is a reference for which allocating memory later is allowed but in C++ that is constant reference to a memory location defined at the time of declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, we have to specify the size of the array when we declare it. This is a design choice from the creator of C++ that goes back to its C origins.

On the other hand, in Java, we only declare a reference to an array object with `int arr[]`. Then we allocate memory for the array with something like `arr = new int[10]` to specify its size.

In Java, arrays are objects, just like String or ArrayList. But that is not the case in C++.

Comment: much better explanation for the question thanks a lot

Comment: You don't have to specify the size if you declare a dynamic array using a pointer.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Then you declare the variable as a *pointer* not as an array.

Comment: Yes, but that is the closest equivalent to the original Java: int *arr;

Comment: @DaveDoknjas And that still doesn't change the fact when you declare a variable as an *array* in C++, you must specify the size.

Answer (score 8):

"Why cannot we declare arrays with an unspecified size" - Because the C++ language standard says you cannot. "like Java" - Because C++ is not Java. Different languages have different design goals/criteria and also different history. If you want a dynamic array in C++, the tool to reach for is `std::vector`.
An array is always statically sized in C++ (even the nicer `std::array`). It needs to know how much space to allocate up-front (which happens at compile time, *not* run-time). This is important for performance, since you know it won't do dynamic reallocations later. It also lets you know the exact memory layout and size of your objects in some cases, which can be important.

You really *cannot* compare languages like you try to. Each has to be learned on its own. You cannot really carry over stuff from one to the other - even if it *looks* similar.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it needs to know how much memory to allocate.

std::vector does memory re-allocation for you under the covers, if you were to implement your own std::vector you could start by declaring an array of a certain size and anytime more memory is needed you adjust.

Comment: so in java the same happens under the hood? hence it is correct in java?

Comment: @cybrpnkkrtos in java every arrays are dynamically allocated. In C++, raw arrays are sized by default because they reside in the stack like other variables.

Answer (score 1):

Java and C++ are actually pretty similar in this area, only the syntax is a little different.

Java:

```
// declare a reference to an array of integers
int[] arr;
// allocate an array of 10 integers on the heap and store a reference in arr
arr = new int[ 10 ];
```

C++:

```
// declare a pointer to an integer, set it to null to be safe
int* arr = nullptr;
// allocate an array of 10 integers on the heap and store a pointer to it in arr
arr = new int[ 10 ];
```

Java makes things a little easier by garbage collecting the array some time after you've finished using it. You can almost get this in C++ using `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` or `std::shared_ptr<int[]>`. Alternatively `std::vector<int>` is often a better choice.

Where you are possibly getting confused is C++'s ability to allocate arrays on the stack. These arrays must be a fixed size declared at compile time. Java does not have this feature, only primitive types and references are allocated on the stack.

You can also declare these fixed sized arrays as object members which then are stored as part of the object. Again Java does not have this feature and objects can only contain references to arrays.